# Center a table in the middle a a page and to center in Y a row

Tags: tables

I want to center a table in the middle of a page and to increase it's size in x and y until the with values that I consider. Also i would like to center the ocntent of a row in Y.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany, oneside,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{xfrac}
% \usepackage[a4paper, total={2in}]{geometry}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

% \maketitle 
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{table}[H] 
\centering 
\resizebox{16.5cm}{!} {
\begin{tabular}{|cccc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Fórmulas y Supuestos para Pruebas de Hipótesis}}                                                                        \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Media Poblacional}}                                                                         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Nula}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Alterna}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Supuestos}}  & \textbf{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu < a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu > a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$ H_0 : \mu = a $}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu \neq a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$\!\begin{aligned}[t]
    &X \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \mu,\sigma_o^2 \right) \\ 
    &\sigma_o^2 : \text{conocida} \\ 
    \end{aligned}$ \\ }} & \multirow{-3}{*}{$ \frac{\bar{X}-a}{\sfrac{\sigma_0}{\sqrt{n}}} \to \mathcal{N}\left( 1,0 \right) $}           \\  \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu < a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu > a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$ H_0 : \mu = a $}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu \neq a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$\!\scriptsize{\begin{aligned}[t]
    &X \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \mu,\sigma_o^2 \right) \\ 
    &\sigma_o^2 : \text{desconocida} \\ 
    &n<30
    \end{aligned}}$ \\{} }}  & \multirow{-3}{*}{$ \frac{\bar{X}-a}{\sfrac{S}{\sqrt{n}}} \to t_{\left(n-1\right)} $}             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Diferencia de Medias Poblacionales}}                                                        \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Nula}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Alterna}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Supuestos}}  & \textbf{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu_x - \mu_y < a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu_x - \mu_y > a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$ H_0 : \mu_x - \mu_y = a $}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu_x - \mu_y \neq a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$\!\scriptsize{\begin{aligned}[t]
    &X \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \mu_x,\sigma_x^2 \right), \, Y \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \mu_y,\sigma_y^2 \right)  \\ 
    & \qquad\qquad \sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2 : \text{conocida} \\  
    & \qquad\qquad n_x,n_y \geq 30 \\
    \end{aligned}}$}}  & \multirow{-3}{*}{$\frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-a}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_x}{n_x} + \frac{\sigma^2_y}{n_y}  }} \to \mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right) $}             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu_x - \mu_y < a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu_x - \mu_y > a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$ H_0 : \mu_x - \mu_y = a $}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$ H_1 : \mu_x - \mu_y \neq a $}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$\!\scriptsize{\begin{aligned}[t]
    &X \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \mu_x,\sigma_x^2 \right), \, Y \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \mu_y,\sigma_y^2 \right)  \\ 
    & \qquad\qquad \sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2 : \text{desconocida} \\  
    & \qquad\qquad n_x,n_y < 30 \\
    \end{aligned}}$}}  & \multirow{-3}{*}{$\frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-a}{\sqrt{\frac{S_x^2 \left( n_x -1\right) + S_y^2 \left( n_y -1\right) }{n_x+n_y-2}}  \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_x} + \frac{1}{n_y}}} \to t_{\left(n_x+n_y-2\right)} $}             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Proporción}}                                                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Hipóstesis Nula}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Alterna}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Supuestos}}  & \textbf{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : p < a$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : p > a$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$H_0 : p=a$}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : p \neq a$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$\!\begin{aligned}[t]
    &X \sim \text{Bernoulli}\left( p \right) \\ 
    &n \geq 30 \\ 
    \end{aligned}$}}  & \multirow{-3}{*}{$ \frac{\hat{p} - a}{\sqrt{\frac{a \left(1-a \right)}{n} }} \to \mathcal{N}\left(1,0\right) $}             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$\hat{p} = \Bar{X}$ (center in Y) }                                                                                                                                                       \\[0.5ex] \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Diferencia de Proporciones}}                                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Nula}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Alterna}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Supuestos}}  & \textbf{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : p_x - p_y > 0$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : p_x - p_y < 0$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$H_0 : p_x - p_y =0$}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : p_x - p_y \neq 0$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$\!\begin{aligned}[t]
    &X \sim \text{Bernoulli}\left( p_x \right), \, Y \sim \text{Bernoulli}\left( p_y \right) \\ 
    & \qquad\qquad\qquad n_x,n_y \geq 30 \\ 
    \end{aligned}$}}  & \multirow{-3}{*}{$ \frac{\hat{p}_x - \hat{p}_y}{\sqrt{ \left(\frac{n_x\hat{p}_x + n_y\hat{p}_y}{n_x+n_y}\right) \left(1 - \frac{n_x\hat{p}_x + n_y\hat{p}_y}{n_x+n_y} \right) \left( \frac{1}{n_x} + \frac{1}{n_y} \right)  }} \to \mathcal{N}\left(1,0\right) $}             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Varianza}}                                                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Nula}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Alterna}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Supuestos}}  & \textbf{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : \sigma^2 < a$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : \sigma^2 > a$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$H_0 : \sigma^2 = a$}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : \sigma^2 \neq a$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\sigma^2\right)$}}  & \multirow{-3}{*}{$\frac{S^2}{a}\left(n-1\right) \to \mathcal{X}^2_{n-1}$}             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Prueba de Hipótesis para las Varianzas de dos Poblaciones}}                                                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Nula}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Hipótesis Alterna}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Supuestos}}  & \textbf{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : \sigma_x^2 < \sigma_y^2$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : \sigma_x^2 > \sigma_y^2$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &                                \\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$H_0 : \frac{\sigma_y^2}{\sigma_x^2} = 1$}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$H_1 : \sigma_x^2 \neq \sigma_y^2$}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{$X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x\right), \, Y \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_y,\sigma^2_y\right)$}}  & \multirow{-3}{*}{$\frac{S_x^2}{S_y^2} \to F_{\left( n_x-1,n_y-1 \right)} $}             \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
}
\end{table} 
\end{center}

\textbf{**Nota}: Para las muestras menores a 30, si la muestra es mayor a 30 se utilizan distribuciones normales $\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right).$


\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you can remove all of these `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ ... }` by changing `|cccc|` into `|c|c|c|c|`. Also, do not place a `table` environment inside a `center` environment. You either want a floating environment (then use `table`), or you don't want it  (then you can use `center`, but not `table` with `\centering`). Finally, you get errors of two misplaced ` \\ ` inside `\multirow` macros which you might want to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever else you do, *do not use* `\resizebox` to shoehorn tables into the width of the textblock -- unless you take special delight in making LaTeX render the table's contents so tiny as to make them virtually illegible. Don't expect many of your readers to share your delight, though...

Instead, do find more linebreak possibilities in the cells, do be prepared to switch to `\scriptsize` in some cells, and do get rid of the large number of pointless `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ ... }` wrappers. These wrappers are not only pointless, they're actually harmful as they prevent line breaks from occurring. In addition, all three instances of `\mathcal{N}\left(1,0\right)` should be `\mathcal{N}(0,1)`, right? By the way, there are many other instances of `\left` and `\right` in your code that don't do anything useful; please get rid of these instances.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany, oneside,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\Bernoulli}{Bernoulli}
\newcommand\headerline[1]{%
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{#1}}}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page dimensions appropriately

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering$}X<{$}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{$}c<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p] 
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| U | U | U | C |}

\hline
\headerline{Fórmulas y \text{Supuestos} para Pruebas de Hipótesis} \\ 
\hline
\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Media Poblacional} \\ 

H_0 & H_1 & \text{Supuestos} & \text{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ 
\hline
 & \mu<a & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
 & \mu>a & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
\multirow{-3}{*}{$\mu=a$} 
  & \mu\ne a 
  & \multirow{-3}{*}{%
    $\begin{gathered}
      X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma_o^2) \\ 
      \sigma_o^2\colon \text{conocida} 
    \end{gathered}$} 
  & \multirow{-3}{*}{%
    $\dfrac{\bar{X}-a}{\sigma_0/\sqrt{n}} \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ } \\  
\hline
 &  \mu < a  & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
 &  \mu > a  & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
\multirow{-3}{*}{$\mu = a$}     
 & \mu \neq a  
 & \multirow{-3}{*}{%
   $\begin{gathered}
    X \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu,\sigma_o^2 ) \\ 
    \sigma_o^2\colon \text{desconocida} \\ 
    n<30
    \end{gathered}$}
 & \multirow{-3}{*}{%
    $\dfrac{\bar{X}-a}{S/\sqrt{n}} \to t_{(n-1)} $} \\ 
\hline

\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Diferencia de Medias Poblacionales} \\ 
%\hline
H_0  & H_1 & \text{Supuestos}  & \text{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ 
\hline
 &  \mu_x - \mu_y < a  & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
 &  \mu_x - \mu_y > a  & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
\multirow{-3}{*}{$\mu_x - \mu_y = a $}     
  &  \mu_x - \mu_y \neq a  
  & \multirow{-3}{*}{\scriptsize
    $\begin{gathered}
    X \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_x,\sigma_x^2 ) \\[-0.1\baselineskip]
    Y \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_y,\sigma_y^2 ) \\[-0.1\baselineskip] 
    \sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2\colon \text{conocida} \\[-0.1\baselineskip]  
    n_x,n_y \geq 30 
    \end{gathered}$}
  & \multirow{-3}{*}{%
    $\dfrac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-a}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_x}{n_x} 
    + \frac{\sigma^2_y}{n_y}  }} \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ } \\ 
\hline
 &  \mu_x - \mu_y < a  & & \\[0.1\baselineskip]
 %\cline{2-2}
 &  \mu_x - \mu_y > a  & & \\[0.1\baselineskip]
 %\cline{2-2}
\multirow{-3}{*}{%
   $\mu_x - \mu_y = a$ }     
  &  \mu_x - \mu_y \neq a 
  & \multirow{-3}{*}{\scriptsize
    $\begin{gathered}
    X \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_x,\sigma_x^2)  \\[-0.1\baselineskip]
    Y \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_y,\sigma_y^2)  \\[-0.1\baselineskip] 
    \sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2\colon \text{desconocida} \\[-0.1\baselineskip]  
    n_x,n_y < 30 \\
    \end{gathered}$}  
 & \multirow{-3}{*}{\footnotesize
   $\begin{gathered}
   \dfrac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-a}{%
     \sqrt{\frac{S_x^2 (n_x-1) + S_y^2 (n_y-1) }{n_x+n_y-2}}  
     \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_x} + \frac{1}{n_y}}} \\[-0.15\baselineskip]
   \to t_{(n_x+n_y-2)} 
   \end{gathered}$} \\ 
%\hline

\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Proporción} \\ 
%\hline
H_0 & H_1 & \text{Supuestos} & \text{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ 
\hline
 & p < a & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
 & p > a & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
\multirow{-3}{*}{$p=a$} 
 & p \neq a 
 & \multirow{-3}{*}{%
   $\begin{gathered}
    X \sim \Bernoulli(p) \\ 
    n \geq 30 \\ 
   \end{gathered}$} 
 & \multirow{-3}{*}{%
    $\dfrac{\hat{p} - a}{\sqrt{a (1-a)/n }} 
    \to \mathcal{N}(0,1) $} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$\hat{p} = \Bar{X}$ (center in $Y$) } \\ 

\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Diferencia de Proporciones} \\ 
H_0  & H_1 & \text{Supuestos}  & \text{Estadístico de Prueba} \\
\hline 
 & p_x - p_y > 0 & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
 & p_x - p_y < 0 & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
\multirow{-3}{*}{$p_x - p_y =0$}
  & p_x - p_y \neq 0 
  & \multirow{-3}{*}{\small
    $\begin{gathered}
    X \sim \Bernoulli(p_x)\\
    Y \sim \Bernoulli(p_y) \\ 
    n_x,n_y \geq 30 \\ 
    \end{gathered}$}  
& \multirow{-3}{*}{\footnotesize
   $\begin{gathered} 
   \frac{\hat{p}_x - \hat{p}_y}{\sqrt{ 
   \left(\frac{n_x\hat{p}_x + n_y\hat{p}_y}{n_x+n_y}\right) \!
   \left(1 - \frac{n_x\hat{p}_x + n_y\hat{p}_y}{n_x+n_y} \right) \!
   \left( \frac{1}{n_x} + \frac{1}{n_y} \right)  }} \\[-0.2\baselineskip]
   \to \mathcal{N}(0,1) 
   \end{gathered}$} \\ 

\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Varianza} \\
H_0  & H_1 & \text{Supuestos}  & \text{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ 
\hline
 & \sigma^2 < a & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
 & \sigma^2 > a & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
\multirow{-3}{*}{$\sigma^2 = a$}
 & \sigma^2 \neq a 
 & \multirow{-3}{*}{$X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$}  
 & \multirow{-3}{*}{%
   $\dfrac{S^2}{a}(n-1) \to \mathcal{X}^2_{n-1}$} \\ 
%\hline

\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para las Varianzas de dos Poblaciones} \\ 
%\hline
H_0  & H_1 & \text{Supuestos}  & \text{Estadístico de Prueba} \\ 
\hline
 & \sigma_x^2 < \sigma_y^2 & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
 & \sigma_x^2 > \sigma_y^2 & & \\ %\cline{2-2}
\multirow{-3}{*}{%
  $\dfrac{\sigma_y^2}{\sigma_x^2} = 1$} 
 & \sigma_x^2 \neq \sigma_y^2 
 & \multirow{-3}{*}{%
   $\begin{gathered}
   X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)\\
   Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_y,\sigma^2_y)
   \end{gathered}$}  
 & \multirow{-3}{*}{$\dfrac{S_x^2}{S_y^2} 
   \to F_{(n_x-1,n_y-1)}$ } \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx} 

\medskip\footnotesize
\textbf{Nota}: Para las muestras menores a 30, si la muestra es 
mayor a 30 se utilizan distribuciones normales $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's a second solution. It's main differences, relative to the first one, are (a) typesetting the header line `H_0 & H_1 & \text{Supuestos} & \text{Estadístico de Prueba}` just once, at the top of the table, (b) inverting gray-scale scheme of the subheader lines for a more open "look", and (c) getting rid of the `\multirow{-3}...` directives (as in [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681688/5001)). All columns, including the `X`-type column on the far right, are now automatically typeset in display-style math mode; no need for any `\scriptsize`-type adjustments inside the cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, 
  %openany, % that's the default for the 'article' document class
  %oneside, % that's also the default for the 'article' document class
  a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % <-- new
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % <-- new

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\Bernoulli}{Bernoulli}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page dimensions appropriately

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering$\displaystyle}X<{$}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}

\newcommand\headerline[1]{%
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{909090}%
  \color{white}\bfseries #1}}

% Typographic struts, as suggested by Claudio Beccari
% in an article in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993:
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.4ex}}       % = `top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % = `bottom' strut

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p] 
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt} % default value: 6pt

%\caption{Fórmulas y Supuestos para Pruebas de Hipótesis}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| U | U | U | C |}

\headerline{Fórmulas y Supuestos para Pruebas de Hipótesis\Tstrut\Bstrut} \\ 
%\hline
H_0 & H_1 & \text{Supuestos} & \text{Estadístico de Prueba\Tstrut\Bstrut} 
\\ 


\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Media Poblacional} \\ 

\mu=a &
\begin{gathered}
  \mu<a\Tstrut \\ \mu>a \\ \mu\ne a\Bstrut
\end{gathered} &
\begin{gathered}
   X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma_0^2) \\ 
   \sigma_0^2\colon \text{conocida} 
\end{gathered} &
\frac{\bar{X}-a}{\sigma_0/\sqrt{n}}\to\mathcal{N}(0,1)\\  
\hline

\mu = a &
\begin{gathered}
  \mu < a \\ \mu > a \\ \mu \ne a\Bstrut  
\end{gathered} &
\begin{gathered}
    X \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu,\sigma_0^{2} )\Tstrut \\ 
    \sigma_0^2\colon \text{desconocida} \\ 
    n<30
\end{gathered} &
\frac{\bar{X}-a}{S/\sqrt{n}} \to t_{(n-1)}  
\\ 


\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Diferencia de Medias Poblacionales} \\ 

\mu_x - \mu_y = a &
\begin{gathered}
   \mu_x-\mu_y<a \\ \mu_x-\mu_y>a \\ \mu_x-\mu_y\ne a
\end{gathered} &     
\begin{gathered}
   X \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_x,\sigma_x^2 )\Tstrut \\
   Y \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_y,\sigma_y^2 ) \\ 
   \sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2\colon \text{conocida} \\  
   n_x,n_y \geq 30\Bstrut 
\end{gathered} &
\frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-a}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_x}{n_x} 
   + \frac{\sigma^2_y}{n_y}  }} \to \mathcal{N}(0,1) 
\\ 
\hline

\mu_x - \mu_y = a &
\begin{gathered}
  \mu_x-\mu_y<a \\ \mu_x-\mu_y>a \\ \mu_x-\mu_y\ne a  
\end{gathered} &
\begin{gathered}
    X \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_x,\sigma_x^2)\Tstrut  \\
    Y \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_y,\sigma_y^2)  \\ 
    \sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2\colon \text{desconocida} \\  
    n_x,n_y < 30\Bstrut \\
\end{gathered} &  
\begin{gathered}
   \frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-a}{%
   \smash[b]{\sqrt{\frac{S_x^2 (n_x-1) + S_y^2 (n_y-1) }{n_x+n_y-2}}}  
   \smash[b]{\sqrt{\frac{1\vphantom{S_y^2}}{n_x} 
       + \frac{1\vphantom{S_y^2}}{n_y}}}} \\
       \addlinespace
   \to t_{(n_x+n_y-2)} 
\end{gathered} 
\\ 


\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Proporción} \\ 
p=a &
\begin{gathered}
  p < a\Tstrut \\ p > a \\ p \ne a\Bstrut 
\end{gathered} & 
\begin{gathered}
    X \sim \Bernoulli(p) \\ 
    n \geq 30 \\ 
\end{gathered} & 
\frac{\hat{p} - a}{\sqrt{a (1-a)/n }} 
    \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)  
\\ 
\hline

\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$\hat{p}=\Bar{X}\Tstrut\Bstrut$ (center in $Y$)} 
\\ 


\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Diferencia de Proporciones} \\ 

p_x - p_y =0 &
\begin{gathered}
  p_x - p_y > 0 \\ p_x - p_y < 0 \\ p_x - p_y \ne 0 
\end{gathered} &
\begin{gathered}
    X \sim \Bernoulli(p_x)\\
    Y \sim \Bernoulli(p_y) \\ 
    n_x,n_y \geq 30 \\ 
\end{gathered} & 
\begin{gathered} 
   \frac{\hat{p}_x - \hat{p}_y\Tstrut}{\sqrt{ \!
   \left(\frac{n_x\hat{p}_x + n_y\hat{p}_y}{n_x+n_y}\right) \!\!
   \left(1 - \frac{n_x\hat{p}_x + n_y\hat{p}_y}{n_x+n_y} \right) \!\!
   \left(\frac{1\vphantom{\hat{p}_y}}{n_x} 
        +\frac{1\vphantom{\hat{p}_y}}{n_y}\right)\!}} \\
   %\addlinespace
   \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)\Bstrut 
\end{gathered} 
\\ 


\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Varianza} \\

\sigma^2 = a &
\begin{gathered}
  \sigma^2 < a\Tstrut \\ \sigma^2 > a \\ \sigma^2\ne a\Bstrut 
\end{gathered} &
X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2) &  
(n-1)\frac{S^2}{a} \to \mathcal{X}^2_{n-1} 
\\ 


\headerline{Prueba de Hipótesis para las Varianzas de dos Poblaciones} \\ 

\frac{\sigma_y^2}{\sigma_x^2} = 1 &
\begin{gathered}
   \sigma_x^2 < \sigma_y^2\Tstrut  \\ 
   \sigma_x^2 > \sigma_y^2  \\ 
   \sigma_x^2 \ne \sigma_y^2\Bstrut 
\end{gathered} &
\begin{gathered}
   X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)\\
   Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_y,\sigma^2_y)
\end{gathered} & 
\frac{S_x^2}{S_y^2} \to F_{(n_x-1,n_y-1)} 
\\ 

\hline
\end{tabularx} 

\medskip\small
\textbf{Notas}. $H_0$: Hipótesis Nula. $H_1$: Hipótesis Alterna. Para las muestras menores a 30, si la muestra es mayor a 30 se utilizan distribuciones normales $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

By use of the `talltblr` table and `nccmath` package for medium size math where are needed, no `multirow` cells

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page dimensions appropriately

\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Bernoulli}{Bernoulli}
\NewTableCommand\subtitle{%
\SetCell[c=4]{c, mode=text,
              bg=gray!30,
              font=\bfseries\footnotesize
                   }
                         }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[p]
    \SetTblrStyle{remark-tag}{font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{remark-text}{font=\footnotesize}
    \addtolength{\jot}{-0.5ex}
    \small
\begin{talltblr}[
remark{Nota} = {Para las muestras menores a 30, si la muestra es
mayor a 30 se utilizan distribuciones normales $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {*{3}{Q[c,m, mode=math]}
                                 X[c,m, mode=math]},
                 row{1}  = {mode=text, font=\bfseries, bg=gray!30},
                 row{2}  = {mode=text, font=\bfseries}
                 }
\SetCell[c=4]{c}    {Fórmulas y Supuestos para Pruebas de Hipótesis \\
                     Prueba de Hipótesis para la Media Poblacional} 
    &   &   &   \\
{Hipóstesis\\ Nula: $H_0$:} 
    &   {Hipótesis\\ Alterna: $H_1$:}
        &   Supuestos
            &   Estadístico de Prueba                               
                \\
\mu=a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu<a\\  \mu>a\\ \mu\ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma_o^2) \\ 
        \medmath{\sigma_o^2\colon \text{conocida}}
            \end{gathered} 
            & \dfrac{\bar{X}-a}{\sigma_0/\sqrt{n}} \to \mathcal{N}(1,0) 
                \\
\mu=a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu<a\\  \mu>a\\ \mu\ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma_o^2)  \\ 
        \medmath{\sigma_o^2\colon \text{desconocida}}\\ 
        \medmath{n<30}
            \end{gathered}
            &   \dfrac{\bar{X}-a}{S/\sqrt{n}} \to t_{(n-1)}
                \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Diferencia de Medias Poblacionales}
    &   &   &   \\
H_0 & H_1
        &   \text{Supuestos}
            &   \text{Estadístico de Prueba}
                \\
\mu_x - \mu_y = a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_x,\sigma_x^2 )  \\
        Y \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_y,\sigma_y^2 )  \\    
        \medmath{\sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2\colon \text{conocida}} \\   
        \medmath{n_x,n_y \geq 30}
            \end{gathered}
            &   \dfrac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-a}
                      {\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_x}{n_x} + \frac{\sigma^2_y}{n_y}  }}
                        \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)
                \\
\mu_x - \mu_y = a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_x,\sigma_x^2 )  \\
        Y \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_y,\sigma_y^2 )  \\
        \medmath{\sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2\colon \text{desconocida}} \\
        \medmath{n_x,n_y \geq 30}
            \end{gathered}
            &   \begin{gathered}
            \dfrac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-a}{%
                \sqrt{\frac{S_x^2 (n_x-1) + S_y^2 (n_y-1) }{n_x+n_y-2}}
                \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_x} + \frac{1}{n_y}}} \\
                    \to t_{(n_x+n_y-2)}
               \end{gathered}                \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Proporción}
    &   &   &   \\
H_0 & H_1
        &   \text{Supuestos}
            &   \text{Estadístico de Prueba}
                \\
p = a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \Bernoulli(p) \\
        \medmath{n \geq 30}
            \end{gathered}
            &   \dfrac{\hat{p} - a}{\sqrt{a (1-a)/n }}
                    \to \mathcal{N}(1,0)                 \\
\SetCell[c=4]{c}    \hat{p} = \Bar{X}\ (\text{center in }Y)
    &   &   &   \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Diferencia de Proporciones}
    &   &   &   \\
H_0 & H_1
        &   \text{Supuestos}
            &   \text{Estadístico de Prueba}
                \\
p_x - p_y =0
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \Bernoulli(p) \\
        Y \sim \Bernoulli(p_y) \\
        \medmath{n_x,n_y \geq 30}
            \end{gathered}
            &   \medmath{\begin{gathered}
           \frac{\hat{p}_x - \hat{p}_y}
                {\sqrt{\Bigl(\frac{n_x\hat{p}_x + n_y\hat{p}_y}{n_x+n_y}\Bigr) 
           \left(1 - \frac{n_x\hat{p}_x + n_y\hat{p}_y}{n_x+n_y} \right) \!
           \left( \frac{1}{n_x} + \frac{1}{n_y} \right)  }} \\
           \to \mathcal{N}(1,0)
               \end{gathered}}
                \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Varianza}
    &   &   &   \\
H_0 & H_1
        &   \text{Supuestos}
            &   \text{Estadístico de Prueba}
                \\
\sigma^2 = a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)
            &    \dfrac{S^2}{a}(n-1) \to \mathcal{X}^2_{n-1}
                \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Varianza}
    &   &   &   \\
H_0 & H_1
        &   \text{Supuestos}
            &   \text{Estadístico de Prueba}
                \\
\frac{\sigma_y^2}{\sigma_x^2} = 1
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
       X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)\\
       Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_y,\sigma^2_y)
            \end{gathered}
            &   \dfrac{S_x^2}{S_y^2} \to F_{(n_x-1,n_y-1)}
                \\
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
just materialized my comment below and from @Mico steal idea for table header:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page dimensions appropriately
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.05}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.95}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Bernoulli}{Bernoulli}
\NewTableCommand\subtitle{%
\SetCell[c=4]{c, mode=text,
              bg=gray!30,
              font=\bfseries\footnotesize
                   }
                         }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \SetTblrStyle{remark-tag}{font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{remark-text}{font=\footnotesize}
    \addtolength{\jot}{-0.5ex}
    \small
\begin{talltblr}[
remark{Nota} = {Para las muestras menores a 30, si la muestra es
mayor a 30 se utilizan distribuciones normales $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {*{3}{Q[c,m, mode=math]}
                                 X[c,m, mode=math]},
                 row{1}  = {mode=text, font=\bfseries, bg=gray!30},
                 row{2}  = {mode=text, font=\bfseries}
                 }
\subtitle{Fórmulas y Supuestos para Pruebas de Hipótesis}
    &   &   &   \\
{Hipóstesis\\ Nula: $H_0$}
    &   {Hipótesis\\ Alterna: $H_1$}
        &   Supuestos
            &   Estadístico de Prueba
                \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Media Poblacional}
    &   &   &   \\
\mu=a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu<a\\  \mu>a\\ \mu\ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma_o^2) \\
        \medmath{\sigma_o^2\colon \text{conocida}}
            \end{gathered}
            & \dfrac{\bar{X}-a}{\sigma_0/\sqrt{n}} \to \mathcal{N}(1,0)
                \\
\mu=a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu<a\\  \mu>a\\ \mu\ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma_o^2)  \\
        \medmath{\sigma_o^2\colon \text{desconocida}}\\
        \medmath{n<30}
            \end{gathered}
            &   \dfrac{\bar{X}-a}{S/\sqrt{n}} \to t_{(n-1)}
                \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Diferencia de Medias Poblacionales}
    &   &   &   \\
\mu_x - \mu_y = a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_x,\sigma_x^2 )  \\
        Y \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_y,\sigma_y^2 )  \\
        \medmath{\sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2\colon \text{conocida}} \\
        \medmath{n_x,n_y \geq 30}
            \end{gathered}
            &   \dfrac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-a}
                      {\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_x}{n_x} + \frac{\sigma^2_y}{n_y}  }}
                        \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)
                \\
\mu_x - \mu_y = a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_x,\sigma_x^2 )  \\
        Y \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu_y,\sigma_y^2 )  \\
        \medmath{\sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2\colon \text{desconocida}} \\
        \medmath{n_x,n_y \geq 30}
            \end{gathered}
            &   \begin{gathered}
            \dfrac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-a}{%
                \sqrt{\frac{S_x^2 (n_x-1) + S_y^2 (n_y-1) }{n_x+n_y-2}}
                \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_x} + \frac{1}{n_y}}} \\
                    \to t_{(n_x+n_y-2)}
               \end{gathered}                \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Proporción}
    &   &   &   \\
p = a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \Bernoulli(p) \\
        \medmath{n \geq 30}
            \end{gathered}
            &   \dfrac{\hat{p} - a}{\sqrt{a (1-a)/n }}
                    \to \mathcal{N}(1,0)                 \\
\SetCell[c=4]{c}    \hat{p} = \Bar{X}\ (\text{center in }Y)
    &   &   &   \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Diferencia de Proporciones}
    &   &   &   \\
p_x - p_y =0
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
        X \sim \Bernoulli(p) \\
        Y \sim \Bernoulli(p_y) \\
        \medmath{n_x,n_y \geq 30}
            \end{gathered}
            &   \medmath{\begin{gathered}
           \frac{\hat{p}_x - \hat{p}_y}
                {\sqrt{\Bigl(\frac{n_x\hat{p}_x + n_y\hat{p}_y}{n_x+n_y}\Bigr)
           \left(1 - \frac{n_x\hat{p}_x + n_y\hat{p}_y}{n_x+n_y} \right) \!
           \left( \frac{1}{n_x} + \frac{1}{n_y} \right)  }} \\
           \to \mathcal{N}(1,0)
               \end{gathered}}
                \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Varianza}
    &   &   &   \\
\sigma^2 = a
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)
            &    \dfrac{S^2}{a}(n-1) \to \mathcal{X}^2_{n-1}
                \\
\subtitle{Prueba de Hipótesis para la Varianza}
    &   &   &   \\
\frac{\sigma_y^2}{\sigma_x^2} = 1
    &   \begin{gathered}
    \mu_x - \mu_y < a\\
    \mu_x - \mu_y > a\\
    \mu_x - \mu>a \ne a
        \end{gathered}
        &   \begin{gathered}
       X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)\\
       Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_y,\sigma^2_y)
            \end{gathered}
            &   \dfrac{S_x^2}{S_y^2} \to F_{(n_x-1,n_y-1)}
                \\
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: I thinking that repeating of table's row `H_0 & H_1
        &   \text{Supuestos}
            &   \text{Estadístico de Prueba}` is unnecessary.

Comment: +1 for figuring out how to get rid of the `\multirow{-3}` wrappers.